# How do you serialize a Parcelable to a String in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, parcelable

I'm writing an **Android** app in **Kotlin** and want to store a Location type into **SQLite** as a string.  A Location is a Parcelable.  Does a Parcelable have a method to serialize to a String?

I want to do something like this:

```
var loc:Location
var str:Sring

... Code to Initialize 'loc'...

str = loc.serilizeToString()
```

Comment: We don't do this as Parcelable is not for this... Also protocol may change and after fx user upgrade device to next android version data can be not compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the object to a `Parcel` and then get the bytes (by calling `Parcel.marshall()`) and convert those to a `String` and store that, but you would be relying on the internal implementation of `Location`. A better approach would be to write your own method that serializes the data that you need from the `Location` object into a `String`. For example, something like this:

```
String s = String.format("%s|%e|%e|%f|%f",
    location.getProvider(),
    location.getLatitude(),
    location.getLongitude(),
    location.getSpeed(),
    location.getBearing()
);
```

When you read it back from the database, you just need to parse your `String` into the component parts, create a new `Location` object and set the individual components on it. Something like this:

```
String s; // Location as String
String[] parts = s.split("|");
Location location = new Location(parts[0]);
location.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(parts[1]));
location.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(parts[2]));
location.setSpeed(Float.valueOf(parts[3]));
location.setBearing(Float.valueOf(parts[4]));
```

Comment: Just realized this code is Java and you wanted Kotlin, I hope it is understandable.